# VueJS - Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to toggle between Dark and Light themes, and i am doing it using the feather icons, I am able to change the theme, but i get an error in the console window. Below shows my code and the error.

**Here is my Code:**

```
  <div class="con-img ml-3">
              <feather-icon v-if="this.$store.state.theme=== 'light'" icon="Icon" v-model="OnChange"  vs-name="theme-mode-light"/>
            </div>
            <div class="con-img ml-3">
              <feather-icon v-if="this.$store.state.theme=== 'dark'" icon="Icon" v-model="OnChange" vs-value="dark" vs-name="theme-mode-light"/>
            </div>
    ...
    watch: {
        layoutType (val) {
          if (val === 'horizontal') {
            if (this.theme === 'semi-dark') this.theme = 'light'
            if (this.navbarType === 'hidden')   this.navbarTypeLocal = 'floating'
            this.$emit('updateNavbarColor', '#fff')
          }
        }
      },
    computed: {
         theme: {
          get ()    { return this.$store.state.theme },
          set (val) { this.$store.dispatch('updateTheme', val) }
        },
    }
    methods: {
          OnChange(theme) {
          this.$store.state.theme = theme
        }
     }
```

**actions.js**

```
 updateTheme ({ commit }, val) {
    commit('UPDATE_THEME', val)
  },
```

**mutation.js**

```
 UPDATE_THEME (state, val)           { state.theme             = val   },
```

Here is the error that i get:

[image]

Can someone please tell me why i am getting this error even though i am able to toggle between themes  and also please tell me how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to update a vuex state directly without using mutation.
If you check the method onChange, you are trying to assign the value directly to the vuex state.
The orthodox way would be updating it using a mutation

you can modify your method to be

```
  methods: {
          OnChange(theme) {
          this.$store.dispatch('updateTheme', theme);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, but if i do it this way i get  this.$store.commit not a function, can you please tell me where should the be placed updateTheme, i have created mutations: and have used updateTheme.

Comment: I have updated the handler name...You need define it under mutations just like how you defined actions in your vuex store.. Can you share me your code for the action 'updateTheme'?

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please tell me how to get rid of that issue.

Comment: did you just create that mutation and action handlers?

Comment: Yes, i am getting vuex.esm.js?2f62:460 [vuex] unknown mutation type: themeUpdate

Comment: I already see that in your computed ...you are calling an action called 'updateTheme'...so I just wanted to confirm if that that was created before or after I posted my answer

Comment: It was created before only.

Comment: Also in your mutation is it state.theme or state.themeClr?

Comment: It is state.theme only but i had just used themClr

Comment: you cant use a variable jus like that...have you defined a state called themeClr in your states section of vuex?

Comment: No only in question i have used that, but in actually used i theme only

Comment: lol, pls post the actual code that you use otherwise it will be really confusing

Comment: please change the terms themeClr to theme in the question

Comment: Update it and check my edited answer...it will work

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it